# Electron second instance's command line arguments are corrupted?

Tags: command-line, electron, single-instance

I am following the example for [requestSingleInstanceLock()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) in the Electron's documentation. For some reason the second instance's command line arguments seem corrupted if the arguments have quoted values with spaces inside. The initial `process.argv` looks just fine, however the `argv` parameter in the [second-instance](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance) event comes split at the spaces adding additional argument values, all values are transformed to lower case, and somewhat presorted.

Is there a way to disable this processing, and eventually pass/get the command line of the second instance as is?

NOTE: I have used `app.makeSingleInstance()` in previous Electron versions, however this API has been removed.

Here's an excerpt from the test app I use:

```
console.log(process.argv);

if (!app.requestSingleInstanceLock()) {
  app.exit();
}

app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, workingDirectory) => {
  console.log('second-instance', argv);
});
```

Here's the result:

```
C:\electron-app-win32-x64>electron-app.exe "/Arg1 Value1" "/Arg2 Value2"

C:\electron-app-win32-x64>
[
  'C:\\electron-app-win32-x64\\electron-app.exe',
  '/Arg1 Value1',
  '/Arg2 Value2'
]
second-instance [   <--- from the same command in another console
  'electron-app.exe',
  '/arg1',
  '/arg2',
  '--allow-file-access-from-files',
  '--original-process-start-time=13232862957593703',
  'value1',
  'value2'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

> Chromium's command-line parsing logic. Chromium treats "switches"
>   (things like --foo or --foo=bar) and "arguments" (things that don't
>   begin with --) separately

You can find links to Chromium source and  some hacks to get around this logic in this github issue.
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20322